# extract particular substring from a string NOT from file

Tags: shell-script, cut

I have a string like below
,extract_name_is_subscriber_date07232017023012.csv,extract_name_is_subscribers1_date07232017023012.csv

is there any way to date only sting from above string
like only

date07232017023012

thanks in advance

Comment: Based on what criteria? That it's inbetween the 4th `_` and the first `.`?

Answer (score 0):

With ***sed***:

```
s=",extract_name_is_subscriber_date07232017023012.csv,extract_name_is_subscribers1_date07232017023012.csv"
sed 's/.*_\([^_.]*\).*/\1/' <<< $s
date07232017023012
```